# how to save page inputs state in angular 2 typescript

Tags: angular

i`m beginner in ng2. i need to save my page state (for ex filter inputs for advanced search page) that after refresh page inputs state for page save.

now i use localstorage and need better solution for this problem. this solution in some case not work as well. in this solution for each page assign a key and save page states in key-value localDB.

thanks

Comment: what is bad about using localStorage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can save your page inputs state in router. for simplicity each filterModels must has two method like pushRouter and pullRouter for set & get states in router.